# MySQL performance tuning for DELETE query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization, sql-delete

Can any one help me to re-write the query to speed up the execution time? It took **37** seconds to execute.

```
DELETE FROM storefront_categories 
WHERE userid IN (SELECT userid 
                FROM MASTER 
                where expirydate<'2020-2-4' 
                )
```

At the same time, this query took only 4.69 seconds only to execute.

```
DELETE FROM storefront_categories 
WHERE userid NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM MASTER)
```

The table **storefront_categories** have **97K** records where as in **MASTER** have **40K** records. We have created a index on MASTER.expirydate field.

Comment: If you're deleting too many records, use it in batches (In addition to add index to speed up the query). ie, Append a limit to the query, like  "LIMIT 1000".

Comment: Are you deleting 40K rows?

Comment: no, maximum 10-20 records after applying the WHERE condition for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting 40K rows, expect it to take time.  The main cost (assuming adequate indexing and a decent query) is the overhead of transactional semantics of an "atomic" delete.  This involves making a copy of each row being deleted, just in case there is a crash.  That way, InnoDB can bring the database back to what it had been before the crash.

When deleting 40% of a table, it is much faster to copy the rows to keep into another table then swap tables.

When deleting a large number of rows (regardless of the percentage), it is better to do it in chunks.  And it is best to walk through the table based on the `PRIMARY KEY`.

I discuss both of those techniques, plus others, in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

As for the query formulation:

- It is version-dependent; old versions of MySQL did a poor job on some flavors.
- `NOT IN (SELECT ...)` and `NOT EXISTS` tend to be the worst performers.
- `IN (SELECT ...)` and/or `EXISTS` may be better.
- "Multi-table `DELETE` is another option.  It works like `JOIN`.
- (Bottom line:  You did not say what version you are running; I can't predict which formulation will be best.)
- My blog avoids the formulation debate.

Comment: it worked. @Rick James, you rocks! You found the right solution about MyISAM.

Comment: @CbproAds - Tip 1:  Mention MyISAM if you ask any further questions; people answering Questions will assume InnoDB and give inappropriate answers.  Tip 2:  Change the Engine to InnoDB.

Answer (score 1):

The query looks fine as it is.

I would suggest the following indexes for optimization:

```
master(expiry_date, userid)
storefront_categories(userid)
```

The first index is a *covering* index for the subquery on `master`: it means that the database should be able to execute the subquery by looking at the index only (whereas with just `expiry_date` in the index, it still needs to look at the table data to fetch the related `userid`).

The second index lets the database optimize the `in` operation.

Comment: GMB,  Thanks for input. It really worked well. The execustion time came down to 3 seconds from 37! However i wonder why DELETE statement is taking 3 seconds where as when i replace DELETE with SELECT on the same statement, it took only 0.09 seconds.. Is it because of any MY.INI performance tuning parameter?

Comment: @CbproAds: `delete` incurs more work for the database, so what you are seeing does not surprise me.

Comment: Having an index _starting_ with `expiry_date` fixes the 37 vs 4.67 performance difference.  Making it "covering" adds an extra boost.

Comment: In really old versions of MySQL, `IN (SELECT ...)` re-evaluated the subquery 97K times!

Answer (score 1):

I would try with `exists` :

```
DELETE 
FROM storefront_categories 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM MASTER M 
              WHERE M.userid = storefront_categories.userid AND
                    M.expirydate <'2020-02-04'  
              );
```

Index would be metter here i would expect index on `storefront_categories(userid) & MASTER(userid, expirydate)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use `NOT EXISTS` with the correct index:

```
DELETE sc
    FROM storefront_categories sc
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM master m
                      WHERE m.userid = sc.userid AND
                            m.expirydate < '2020-02-04' 
                     );
```

The index you want is on `master(userid, expirydate)`.  The order of the columns is important.  For this version, an index on `storefront_categories` does not help.

Note that I changed the date format.  I recommend using YYYY-MM-DD to avoid ambiguity -- and to use the full 10 characters.